# generate css so that the color of the font changes based on the user's input using Django session

Tags: python, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am very new to python and Django and I am trying to create an app where the css of the words changes based on the user's selected color. following code shows how I am adding everything to session.

```
def submit(request):
    if 'counter' in request.session:
        request.session['counter'] += 1
    else:
        request.session['counter'] = 1

    request.session['data']['word'].append(request.POST['words'])
    request.session['data']['color'].append(request.POST['color'])
    request.session['data']['font'].append(request.POST['bigFont'])


    return redirect('/result')
```

This is how I am trying to check it in the html file..

```
<form action="/clear_session">
        You have requested word these many times: {{request.session.counter}}

        {% for key,value in request.session.data.iteritems %}
        <p>{{key}}: {{value}}</p>
        {%if value=="Red":%}
        <p style="color:red;font-size: 20px;">request.session.data.word</p>
        {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}

        <input type="submit" value="Clear Session"> 
    </form>
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /result
Could not parse the remainder: '=="Red":' from
```

what am I doing wrong? Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: Could you include more of the error?

Comment: Also, can you try removing the : from the if?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code but without ‘:’

```
    {% if value is “Red” %}
```